# Is it possible to display reactive input and output values in a dynamic Rmarkdown report outside of a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, reactive-programming, reporting

I can't access Shiny inputs and outputs outside of the widget, in the body of the Rmarkdown report.

I would like to create a dynamic report with Rmarkdown.

It includes a Shiny widget (a simple calculator, in-line).

I'd like to use the reactive input and output values in the body of the report, to be able to discuss to findings in detail, but outside a Shiny widget.

Can I "cite" outputs of the shiny app in the body of the report without scope issues?

Can I also use those output values to run more analysis with R, outside the Shiny app?

Is it possible? Is it not supported? Or perhaps there is a better workaround than my current approach?